# remote ftp account but with the my normal domain name

Tags: ftp, dns

I want to have an ftp account thisaccount@mydomain.com that does not access my normal mydomain.com server but accesses any other remote server from some service provider.

How do i do this with still keeping mydomain in the address? Which service providers would just give me an ftp account without moving my domian there? Do i need to investigate ftp redirects?

Any direction appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to setup a dns CNAME to yourftpprovider.com from ftp.mydomain.com.

An example entry in the zone file for mydomain.com:

```
ftp IN CNAME yourftpprovider.com.
```